# How to modify java code in android studio which I used by importing from a api

Tags: java, android

I have using a api from github for country code picker. Through that, I am getting selected country code and flag.
I am using that by importing in my activity.But I want to do some change in that code in my activity.
When I am clicking on control+space on a method which I am using from that api, I am getting .class file. So I cannot able to do changes in that.

```
https://github.com/jitenderdev/countryutility/blob/master/countryutil/src/main/java/com/jdev/countryutil/CountriesActivity.java
```

I want to make changes in countriesActivity class in my activity alone.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_right_to_left_return,
                R.anim.anim_left_to_right_return);
    }
```

in a overriding method above I want to add finish() method.
this is what I want to do.. Anybody please help me out...

Comment: No, you cannot change .class file code. If you want to change code then you have to import that library as module

Comment: Thank you@Silversky Technology.  Suggest me any api for country picker. I want a country picker layout and also want to get selected country's ISD code, name and flag